# WebClient request level timeout Throws Operator called default onErrorDropped

Tags: java, spring-webflux, embedded-jetty, project-reactor

We are using Spring Reactive WebClient to make http calls. It uses JettyClientHttpConnector underneath. To set request level timeouts we use The Mono timeout API.

If there is no response from the server, the mono times out, but it also throws

```
Operator called default onErrorDropped java.lang.InterruptedException
```

After few instances of this error we get insufficient thread issue in jetty connection pool.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Insufficient configured threads: required=200 \u003c max=200 for QueuedThreadPool[HttpClient@49e4c2d5]@687d1782{STARTED,8\u003c=199\u003c=200,i=1,q=0}[ReservedThreadExecutor@3eaa0b62{s=0/1,p=0}]
```

We suspect due to onErrorDropped exception, the connections are not getting released. How to make sure the connection resources are getting released after the Mono timeout?

Dependency

```
org.springframework:spring-webflux:jar:5.1.4.RELEASE
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty:jar:2.1.2.RELEASE
org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-reactive:jar:2.2.0.M1
```

WebClient config

```java
WebClient.Builder.clone()
.clientConnector(new JettyClientHttpConnector(new HttpClient())).build();
```

Client call

```java
URI request = UriComponentsBuilder
.fromUriString("foo")
.path("/path")
.build();

return webClient.put()
   .uri(request)
   .body(BodyInserters.fromObject(fooBar))
   .retrieve()
   .onStatus(HttpStatus::isError, clientResponse -> 
 clientResponse.toEntity(String.class)
                .map(body -> new RunTimeException(body.toString())))
   .bodyToMono(Foo2.class)
   .timeout(Duration.ofMillis(100))
   .retry(3, retryError -> retryError instanceof TimeoutException);
```

Exception

Mono Timeout:-

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Did not observe any item or terminal signal within 500ms in 'lift' (and no fallback has been configured)
```

```
reactor.core.publisher.Operators         : Operator called default onErrorDropped java.lang.InterruptedException: null
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:998) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
        at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:231) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector.doStart(ManagedSelector.java:106) ~[jetty-io-9.4.14.v20181114.jar!/:9.4.14.v20181114]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) ~[jetty-util-9.4.14.v20181114.jar!/:9.4.14.v20181114]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138) ~[jetty-util-9.4.14.v20181114.jar!/:9.4.14.v20181114]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108) ~[jetty-util-9.4.14.v20181114.jar!/:9.4.14.v20181114]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager.doStart(SelectorManager.java:262) ~[jetty-io-9.4.14.v20181114.jar!/:9.4.14.v20181114]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) ~[jetty-util-9.4.14.v20181114.jar!/:9.4.14.v20181114]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138) ~[jetty-util-9.4.14.v20181114.jar!/:9.4.14.v20181114]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108) ~[jetty-util-9.4.14.v20181114.jar!/:9.4.14.v20181114]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.AbstractConnectorHttpClientTransport.doStart(AbstractConnectorHttpClientTransport.java:64) ~[jetty-client-9.4.14.v20181114.jar!/:9.4.14.v20181114]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) ~[jetty-util-9.4.14.v20181114.jar!/:9.4.14.v20181114]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138) ~[jetty-util-9.4.14.v20181114.jar!/:9.4.14.v20181114]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108) ~[jetty-util-9.4.14.v20181114.jar!/:9.4.14.v20181114]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient.doStart(HttpClient.java:250) ~[jetty-client-9.4.14.v20181114.jar!/:9.4.14.v20181114]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) ~[jetty-util-9.4.14.v20181114.jar!/:9.4.14.v20181114]
        at org.springframework.http.client.reactive.JettyClientHttpConnector.connect(JettyClientHttpConnector.java:98) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.exchange(ExchangeFunctions.java:103) ~[spring-webflux-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:118) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:96) [spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121) [reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:96) [spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1505) [reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:241) [reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:96) [spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.onNext(MonoSubscribeOn.java:143) [reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:96) [spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1505) [reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCallable.subscribe(MonoCallable.java:61) [reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoLiftFuseable.subscribe(MonoLiftFuseable.java:55) [reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3695) [reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.run(MonoSubscribeOn.java:123) [reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:84) [reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:37) [reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.async.TraceCallable.call(TraceCallable.java:70) [spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_192]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [na:1.8.0_192]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.8.0_192]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_192]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_192]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_192]
```

```
reactor.core.scheduler.Schedulers        : Scheduler worker in group main failed with an uncaught exception java.lang.InterruptedException: null
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:998) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
        at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:231) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ManagedSelector.doStart(ManagedSelector.java:106) ~[jetty-io-9.4.14.v20181114.jar!/:9.4.14.v20181114]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) ~[jetty-util-9.4.14.v20181114.jar!/:9.4.14.v20181114]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138) ~[jetty-util-9.4.14.v20181114.jar!/:9.4.14.v20181114]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108) ~[jetty-util-9.4.14.v20181114.jar!/:9.4.14.v20181114]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectorManager.doStart(SelectorManager.java:262) ~[jetty-io-9.4.14.v20181114.jar!/:9.4.14.v20181114]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) ~[jetty-util-9.4.14.v20181114.jar!/:9.4.14.v20181114]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138) ~[jetty-util-9.4.14.v20181114.jar!/:9.4.14.v20181114]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108) ~[jetty-util-9.4.14.v20181114.jar!/:9.4.14.v20181114]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.AbstractConnectorHttpClientTransport.doStart(AbstractConnectorHttpClientTransport.java:64) ~[jetty-client-9.4.14.v20181114.jar!/:9.4.14.v20181114]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) ~[jetty-util-9.4.14.v20181114.jar!/:9.4.14.v20181114]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:138) ~[jetty-util-9.4.14.v20181114.jar!/:9.4.14.v20181114]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:108) ~[jetty-util-9.4.14.v20181114.jar!/:9.4.14.v20181114]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient.doStart(HttpClient.java:250) ~[jetty-client-9.4.14.v20181114.jar!/:9.4.14.v20181114]
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68) ~[jetty-util-9.4.14.v20181114.jar!/:9.4.14.v20181114]
        at org.springframework.http.client.reactive.JettyClientHttpConnector.connect(JettyClientHttpConnector.java:98) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.exchange(ExchangeFunctions.java:103) ~[spring-webflux-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar!/:5.1.4.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:118) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:96) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:96) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1505) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:241) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:96) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.onNext(MonoSubscribeOn.java:143) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:96) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1505) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCallable.subscribe(MonoCallable.java:61) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoLiftFuseable.subscribe(MonoLiftFuseable.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3695) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnSubscriber.run(MonoSubscribeOn.java:123) ~[reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:84) [reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at reactor.core.scheduler.WorkerTask.call(WorkerTask.java:37) [reactor-core-3.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:3.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.async.TraceCallable.call(TraceCallable.java:70) ~[spring-cloud-sleuth-core-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.1.1.RELEASE]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_192]
```

Comment: you should define timeouts for webclient https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-builder-reactor-timeout

Comment: @ThomasAndolf We want to set timeout per request level, setting the timeout at the client level removes that flexibility.

Comment: `Mono#timeout` has nothing to do with the webclient connection. Webclient timeouts work on a tcp level, while `Mono#timeout` works on a emitting level.

Answer (score 1):

That category of errors (`onXxxDropped`) represents "protocol errors", where a signal is received that doesn't comply to the Reactive Streams spec. Here an `onError` signal (the `InterruptedException`) is received after another `onError` (the timeout).

I'm not sure what causes the interruption (jetty or webflux), and whether or not the root cause can be fixed in the WebClient, but you could register a **global** hook to change the default `onErrorDropped` behavior (see `Hooks#onErrorDropped(Consumer)`).

Alternatively, you *can* register a **local** hook on the problematic `Flux` with the following (**un-supported**) piece of code:

```
Flux<T> doubleErroringFlux;
Consumer<Throwable> droppedErrorConsumer = ...;
Flux<T> fluxToUser = doubleErroringFlux
    .subscriberContext(Context.of("reactor.onErrorDropped.local",
    droppedErrorConsumer);
fluxToUse.subscribe(); //or pass down the method, or whatever
```

Comment: In the consumer is it possible to tell the `WebClient` to return the connection to pool, so as to avoid insufficient threads issue?

Comment: no, but it shouldn't be necessary. timeout triggers a cancel upstream, so resources like the connection should be properly clraned

Comment: I have updated the complete stack trace, it seems the `InterruptedException` is coming from jetty `HttpClient`. I think the issue is not with `MonoTimeout` but the `InterruptedException`. Does that need separate handling to make sure resources are released.